# Network Provider doesn't work sometimes when the Device not connected to the Internet

Tags: android

I have an Application that gets Location updates every few minutes. This works great when my phone is connected to wifi/3g. But when I disable the Wi-fi/Data connection its very intermittent, i.e. if I move to some locations it works great but sometimes it just wouldn't pick a signal from the cell tower.

Could this be because there is a bad signal or the phone does needs to be connected to 3G/Wi-fi in order for the Network Provider to work?

I don't want to resort to GPS since although its very accurate, the device needs to be in contact with the satellites in order to get a fix. Also, if it can't get a fix, will this break the Application?

Answer (score 0):

The network provider requires a connection to the network to work.  Its algorithm is to detect what towers it can see and their signal strengths and tries to triangulate a location.  For further accuracy it also uses Wifi SSIDs.  If it isn't connected to those sources, it has no way of telling where you are.

Comment: But does this mean that a normal GSM connection can suffice as well even if the device doesn't have a 3G/Data Connection?

Answer (score 0):

Yes internet connection is necessary for the network provider. The device can get some information from the cellular signals and wifi hotspots in the area but it can't detect the location. The device uses this information to query a backend server which can then lookup its database and give an approximate location. To minimize network transactions, it can prefetch some location information. If the device moves out of this "prefetch" area, it needs internet connection again.

This question has already been asked in Stackoverflow (which is how I came to know of it in the first place) but I can't find it. Do search for it, it has good explanation of how the network provider works.